# Footer over page content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stick the foot on the bottom of my page. For that, I read lots of web sites and all of them tells me the same.

After I have done what was mentioned, my footer really stuck on the bottom... BUT... the content of the page is covered by this!

My CSS has these properties:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-image: url("../img/bg2.jpg");
}

.geral {
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 900px;
}

.container img {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}

.container .btn_criar_conta {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.container .user_detail {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

#topo_pagina {
  height: 110px;
}



.box_login_conteiner {
  width: 410px;
  text-align: left;
}

.box_login {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  color: grey;
  box-shadow: lightgrey 0.0em 0.5em 0.9em;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.box_login li {
  list-style: none;
}

.box_login a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box_login a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box_login input {
  border: 1px whitesmoke solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: lightgrey 0.0em 0.1em 0.1em;
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.box_login .img {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
}

.box_login .btn_submit {
  border: 1px seagreen solid;
  border-radius: 2em;
  box-shadow: grey 0.0em 0.1em 0.1em;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: seagreen;
}

.index_login {
  text-align: justify;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  color: #2b3856;
  font-family: Geneva;
}

.index_login img{
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
}

.index_login hr {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 0px;
}

.info_login {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  color: grey;
}

.info_login a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info_login a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


.box_registrar_conteiner {
  width: 430px;
  text-align: left;
}

.box_registrar {
  width: 430px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  color: grey;
  box-shadow: lightgrey 0.0em 0.5em 0.9em;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.box_registrar li {
  list-style: none;
}

.box_registrar a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box_registrar a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box_registrar input {
  border: 1px whitesmoke solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: lightgrey 0.0em 0.1em 0.1em;
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

.box_registrar .img {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
}


.rodape {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: Geneva;
  font-size: 11px;
}


.rodape a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.rodape a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.rodape #menu {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.container_footer {
  width: 900px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

And my HTML is like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="geral">
            <div id="topo_pagina">
                <div align="center">
                    <div class="container">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <a href="/"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo1.png"></a>

                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <div class="user_detail">
                                <br/>
                                Olá {{ user.first_name|capfirst }}! - <a href="/logout/">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="/login/"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/btn_logar_conta.png" class="btn_criar_conta"></a>
                            <a href="/registrar/"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/btn_criar_conta.png" class="btn_criar_conta"></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="conteudo_pagina">
                <div align="center">
                    <div class="container">
                    {% block conteudo_pagina %}
                    {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <br clear="all">
            <div class="rodape">
                <div align="center">
                    <div class="container_footer">
                        <div id="menu">
                            <h4>Multiplikação</h4>
                            <a href="/login/">Acessar</a><br/>
                            <a href="/registrar/">Criar conta</a><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <h4>Sobre a empresa</h4>
                            Quem somos<br/>
                            Nosso time<br/>
                            Trabalhe com a gente<br/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <h4>Conectividade</h4>
                            Facebook<br/>
                            Twitter<br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me? I really don't know what to try. =(

Thanks in advance for all!

Comment: Content of the page is covered by what? What is *this*?

Comment: I know this is not the perfect example of organized code, but as I am not experienced on web development and just want to make this work, please, try not to pay so much attention on this. =)

Comment: You misunderstood. You said: *the content of the page is covered by this*. What is *this*? You mean the footer?

Comment: Yes, the footer. When I open the page, where the content in short the footer keeps on the bottom, exactly as it should be. But when I have a larger content, seems that the footer keeps on the bottom, but the text goes behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Fiddle with your markup modified to implement a sticky footer:

http://jsfiddle.net/2MXvP/1/

The technique I have used is this one: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

The significant changes are:

- The `.rodape` element has been moved in the markup so it is a sibling of `.geral`.
- `.rodape` has a negative top margin equivalent to its height.
- `.geral` has a new child element, `.main`, which has bottom padding equivalant to the height of `.rodape`.

I might have made some other CSS changes too, but only to `.rodape`, `.geral` and `.main`.

If you look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ I linked to above you should be able to figure out how it works. There are some notes on that page about IE and Opera compatibility, which I have not implemented in my Fiddle, and I only tested in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the footer to be visible at all times, but you don't want the very bottom of your content to be covered up by it. If that's the case, you can add a padding-bottom property to your .geral class.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure which  is your footer here, and nothing in your CSS is really helping me figure it out, but here's an example anyways, assuming your footer is 200px tall:

```
.geral {padding-bottom:200px}
```

Should give you the exact amount of space to see the footer without it covering up anything.

**EDIT**
If you want it to be constantly visible, but not covering up text, take .rodape out of .geral and put it inside the body tag. Your html should like this now:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="rodape">
             <!-- rodape content -->
        </div>
        <div class="geral">
             <!-- geral content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Add this style to your CSS

```
.rodape {width:100%; height:200px; position:fixed;}
.geral {padding-bottom:200px;}
```

I think that will get you the effect you desire.

Comment: Actually I want my footer always at the end of the page. Not covering up anything, but when I don't have much content in the page it shouldn't be at the middle of the page, but at the bottom. When I do what I exposed in the code above, my footer keeps at the bottom, but when I increase the content it doesn't go down with the content, but keep stuck at the same place and the content seem to be passing behing it (footer).

Comment: Which class represents your footer in CSS you provided?

Comment: ".rodape" - I am sorry, it is in Portuguese, as I am from Brazil.=)

Comment: Made a change, I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

> Remove `position: absolute;` from your css (line 189 of your css above).

The reason why your footer is covering the content is because its positioning is *absolute*, thus taking it out of the normal flow of the content. Once you remove the line mentioned above, .rodape will be statically positioned by default - it will then take into account the elements before it (e.g. #conteudo_pagina) and it will be placed after them (without covering them).

**One thing you might want to know:**

`<br clear="all">` uses *clear*, a deprecated HTML attribute that you DO NOT want to use in your css. Try using padding as suggested by ABCaesar instead.

Comment: That won't make the footer stick to the bottom of the viewport, which is what user1072627 has asked for.

Comment: Ah. Now I get it (saw the sticky footer URL). I couldn't understand what he wanted at first - thought he just wanted the footer to be at the bottom without covering the content. Thumbs up for the URL anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I want the footer to be at the bottom without covering the content. But when I don't have much content in the page, the footer must be at the bottom of the page too.

Comment: Even after removing the "position: absolute" it stills cover the footer. =(

Comment: That's impossible. I tested your code above on my side, and it was the position:absolute that's causing the coverup. Do you have an URL to your latest page? It might be some other styling that's causing the problem, but not stated above. It will be easier for me to look at your page directly and find out the problem.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/nuF5f/4/. You will see that below the dummy text, there is space before the footer & the footer doesn't cover up the text. This is coz' in the top right hand box on this page, I have commented out the position:absolute declaration in the .rodape area.